# How can I make a button swipe left in Android

Tags: java, android

This is my first questions, so I apologise if the format is a little wrong.

I am currently working on a project in Android Studio where I need to make a button dynamically that will swipe left (like something seen in Mail for an iPhone). I know that there has been numerous questions about swiping posted here, but I couldn't find anything that specifically answer my question. I have posted my code below. Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information.

```
public class ViewHistoryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   //list holding the pre-sorted logs stored in database
   private ArrayList<WorkoutLog> logHistory;
   private GestureDetectorCompat gd;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_history);
      logHistory = new ArrayList<WorkoutLog>();
      // Create database handler. This allows easy interaction with
      // the app's database.
      DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      // Get sorted (by date) ArrayList of WorkoutLogs.
      logHistory = (ArrayList<WorkoutLog>) db.getAllWorkoutLogs();
      //loop that creates buttons based on the number of logs stored in the database
      //these buttons will be scrollable because of the xml file. Clicking on a button will
      //bring you to another activity in which you can see the contents of the log
      for (int i==0; i<logHistory.size(); i++) {
         //new button being created for log
         Button myButton = new Button(this);
         //set the text of the log to be the logs title (will add date later)
         myButton.setText(logHistory.get(i).getLogTitle() + "\n" + logHistory.get(i).getLogDateString() + "\n\n\n");
         //needed because logHistory was complaining below for intent.putExtra(...)
         final int test = i;
         //allows user to click on it
         myButton.setClickable(true);
         //when the button is click on by the user, starts the new activity with the detailed
         //log information.  Right now, when clicked on the log just returns to the main page
         myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(ViewHistoryActivity.this, ViewHistoryDetailed.class);
           intent.putExtra("logID",String.valueOf(logHistory.get(test).getLogID()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                gd = new GestureDetectorCompat(ViewHistoryActivity.this, new MyGestureListener());
                gd.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
            class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
                //private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
                private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
                private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewHistoryActivity.this, "got to onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewHistoryActivity.this, "Got to here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    boolean result = false;
                    try {
                        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                           if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                              if (diffX > 0) {
                                 onSwipeRight();
                              } else {
                                  // onSwipeLeft();
                              }
                           }
                           result = true;
                        } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffY > 0) {
                               // onSwipeBottom();
                            } else {
                               // onSwipeTop();
                            }
                        }
                        result = true;
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return result;
                }
                public void onSwipeRight() {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewHistoryActivity.this, "Caught swipe left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //gets the layout of this class, which has been nested inside a scrollable interface
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.View_History);
        //sets button parameters
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //adds button to the layout
        layout.addView(myButton, lp);
    }
}
```

Right now, whenever I click down, it gives me a Toast message, "onDown was clicked". But whenever I try to fling, it doesn't do anything- I don't get any messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise your `GestureDetectorCompat` (gd) in `onCreate` not everytime an onTouch event occurs.

Try moving the below code into `onCreate`

```
gd = new GestureDetectorCompat(ViewHistoryActivity.this, new MyGestureListener());
```

The `GestureDetector` keeps a reference of all the different `MotionEvents` (Down, Move, Up) so that it can calculate the movement and speed of the fling. If it gets initialised each time an event occurs it will never be able to calculate the full sequence of `MotionEvents` (only the last `MotionEvent`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that does make sense.  I tried doing that beforehand, but it gives me the error, "Cannot resolve symbol MyGestureListener() ".  I believe this is because that class is embedded within the onTouchListener() method.  Any suggestions about how to fix that?

Comment: Move MyGestureListener out of the onTouchListener. Either put it in a separate class or put it as an inner class of ViewHistoryActivity. I'd suggest reading up on how classes work in Java as it will be an uphill struggle if you're not clear on that, better to be clear about Java fundamentals before venturing into Android is my recommendation.